# Are some Central Asian countries missing from map in R?

Tags: r

I'm plotting a filled contour over a map in R but some of the Central Asian countries' borders aren't showing (e.g. Kazakhstan, Kyrgyzstan, Tajikistan and Uzbekistan).

The borders don't appear for me using the `map()` function on its own either with `library(maps)` and `library(mapdata)`.

Code:

```
map()
```

Are the borders missing from "map" or have I excluded them somehow?

---

**UPDATE:** the Central Asian countries started appearing in my plots for map("world"), but not map("worldHires"), so if someone out there fixed it: thank you! (I also noticed that the countries were missing from images on a couple of R mapping tutorials (e.g. [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-beginners-plotting-locations-on-to-a-world-map/) and [here](https://www.students.ncl.ac.uk/keith.newman/r/maps-in-r)) so hopefully it was a real problem and it wasn't just me doing something wrong.)

Comment: It's easier to help if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with data that we can run to verify the results and suggest possible solutions (make sure all variables are defined any non-base packages are explicitly listed)

Comment: The countries also appear to be missing with just using: map()

Comment: ...and I'm using the "maps" and "mapdata" libraries.

Comment: #1 Edit your post and make it copy-paste-run'able. #2 Use `map("world")`, which also plots the caspian sea as a hole.